# Ruby on Rails - Devise Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

when we install the gem Devise, the corresponding views are automatically created?

I've installed the gem on an existing model User and it's letting me do the registration and login, but I can't seem to find the folder containing the views...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it's been said in docs ( https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views ), to generate views run:

```
rails g devise:views user
```